# Min over time using mysql

Tags: mysql, aggregate

I can generate the data for the left four columns of this data set using mysql - however i want the database to generate the column on the right for (I did this manually as an exmaple).

The column on the right "Best Time So Far For Dist" is essentially the min() of time by dist and competitor where the Date < the current row - but i am failing badly. Can someone please put me out of my misery.

I am not sure whether i need to use variables or a windowed query?

| Date | Competitor | Dist | Time | Best Time So Far For Dist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19933000 | 42 | 8 | 96.48393188 | 96.48393188 |
| 19930871 | 42 | 9 | 114.8276119 | 114.8276119 |
| 19931026 | 42 | 8 | 103.25 | 96.48393188 |
| 19931153 | 42 | 8 | 102.7552456 | 96.48393188 |
| 19932256 | 42 | 8 | 94.76384954 | 96.48393188 |
| 19932656 | 42 | 10 | 126.4790727 | 126.4790727 |
| 19931573 | 42 | 8 | 105.0878202 | 96.48393188 |
| 19931858 | 42 | 8 | 102.3251968 | 96.48393188 |
| 19942916 | 42 | 8 | 103.4234733 | 96.48393188 |
| 19943219 | 42 | 8 | 99.43399877 | 96.48393188 |
| 19943371 | 42 | 12 | 157.4419526 | 157.4419526 |
| 19942242 | 42 | 9 | 114.9577794 | 114.8276119 |
| 19942726 | 42 | 9 | 109.0333779 | 109.0333779 |
| 19941551 | 42 | 8 | 108.8026135 | 96.48393188 |
| 19941892 | 42 | 8 | 100.3004317 | 96.48393188 |

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There needs to be another column to provide order, because your dates are not in order, we can't use that for the order. Without that, we can't say what "so far" means, because rows do not have an implicit order. So I added an `id` primary key column.

```
select *, min(time) over (partition by dist order by id) as 'Best time so far for Dist'
from mytable
order by id;
```

[Demo DbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/htn6TOFF)

Comment: You my friend are an absolute hero! Thank you for your help it is much appreciated.